# How to full size the background image?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put full size in the background image, the height works fine but the width don't works.

here the index.html.er file:

```
<!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h1 class="brand-heading">Mota Project Live</h1>
                        <p class="intro-text">Have a joy with Mota Project Live the most experimental music.<br>Let's Join us and Joy!</p>
                        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Here the application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Mota Project Live" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Mota Project Live" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
    <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class= "container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my .scss file:

```
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url('intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}

.intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 80px;
}

.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: I think if you give "header" tag width 100% then it may be it will work. please try that.

Comment: add background-size:100%; in css

Comment: Hi  SachinR, I put the header tag: header{ width: 100%; }  and don't work's. Thank's!

Comment: I've set up a fiddle using just your code (but with a hosted image) and it seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/Lbzghx55/ . What is the unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

background-attachment:  fixed; behaves like position: fixed and so the image is removed from the document flow, and thus background-size:cover; has no effect.

As an aside, you almost certainly don't need to vendor prefix background-size. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: I cut the `background-attachment: fixed` and do nothing. Thank's Paul Green.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line in `.into` class

```
  background: url('intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom 100% scroll;
```

Comment: Hi Arslan, I try this 100% and the image was hidden. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

I fix that problem and the solution for the problem was in the grid. what I do was change the application.html.erb file and the `class="container"` in main for `fluid`. I change for:

```
<main role="main" class= "container-fluid">
```

and works perfectly. And the problem wasn't in the css file. Thank you Guys for the Help.